# Add Gesture Recogniser to UISlider Thumb / Handle with Swift

Tags: swift, gesture, uislider

I've been struggling with this for a few evenings. I want to add a gesture recogniser to the handle on a custom UISlider (Double-tapping it will reset the value).

I've tried lots of different approaches (trying to find the properties of the handle onChange then adding a gesture recogniser to a CGRect... trying to add a gesture recogniser to the currentThumbImage...) and have had no luck.

What approach should I be taking?